# Unable to run 64-bit guest OSes in Oracle Virtual Box after Windows reinstall

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, bios, 64-bit, virtualization

I have resinstalled my Windows 10 and now can't run Oracle Virtual Box guest OSes in 64 bit.

There is no bitness setiing in VB anymore

[image]

Guest OS has 32-bit prefix now:

[image]

Althoug image is 64 bit.

Error messages vary, most often is just black screen. If run Ubuntu installer, it explicitly fails due to bitness.

I have 64-bit host OS.

[image]

I have Hyper-V diabled in Windows:

[image]

I have Intel Virtualization enabled in BIOS.

I didn't find any VT-d setting in BIOS.

[image]

What can be wrong?

Comment: "Correct" option was in unexpected place. I said that, virtual machines were existing already. It is strange that everything was saved in their profiles except bitness and the bitness was not in settings, but in OS dropdown.

Comment: First you said, that you judge "based on my answer", now you say it was "always" that. Okay.

Answer (score 0):

Incredible!

It was enough to set 64-bit here:

[image]